List of mosaico templates not visible
Similar to Mosaico template list table not rendering - I can see a table with the right number of rows, but each table cell is blank.
There is no error in the console or the logs.
I do see that in the network tab, it stops with an api call, whereas a functioning install has a rest call immediately after that is missing in the non-functioning site.
Looking at the searchkit search and form, it seems to be failing at the table level (where a bunch of content is being rewritten, presumably for angular).
This is an old multilingual civicrm, so that might be related. This issue doesn't seem to interfere with anything else (in fact, it's probably been an issue for a while, and only just noticed).

Here's my solution in the form of a narrative ...

The problem can be narrowed down a bit. That page/display is just a display ('Mosaico_Template_List') of a packaged searchkit (also called 'Mosaico_Template_List').

When I edit that packaged search - I can see the list of templates in the basic search, but not in the 'display' (table). That suggests it's an issue with the column definitions.

The columns of this table appear in the UI as "{{$ctrl.parent.getColLabel(col)}}" which seems weird. Also, when running the preview, I see a lot of console errors (which didn't show up for the actual display).

For a working site, those columns look different and more normal.


Perhaps this packaged search was from an earlier mosaico that didn't get updated properly? If I just edit those columns to match what I have in the working site, maybe it'll be fixed?
Yes!
Conclusion: if you have issues with the mosaico templates listing, try directly editing the packaged search called "Mosaico Templates" in the SearchKit listing.
